# How to save custom data in quote item and sales order item table?

Tags: magento2

I have created custom field i.e details field in `quote_item` and `sales_order_item` table. Now I want to store custom field data in details field. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but I just came across your question and I think I have your solution.

First, get the quote from session:
`$quote = $this->session->getQuote()`

Then, get the items from the quote:
`$quoteItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems()`

From here, you can call 'setData' on each item:
`foreach ($quoteItems as $item) { $item->setData('custom_field', val) }`

Then, update the quote with the updated items:
`$quote->setItems($quoteItems)`

Lastly, just save the quote (here using Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface):
`$this->cartRepositoryInterface->save($quote)`

Hope that helps.  Let me know if I misunderstood or can clarify anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use Extension Attributes.

Extension attributes are new in Magento 2. They are used to extend functionality and often use more complex data types.

For more info,

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html

Answer (score 0):

You create a new column in 'sales_quote_item' & 'sales_order_item' table and save the value corresponding to each item there.

or

You have to create 2 custom table with following fields: -

'entity_id','item_id', 'attribute_value'

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same problem.
I added the same field to sales_order_item by adding a quote_item table custom field.
It will be saved automatically.
I hope I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

> To save quote table in etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Api\PaymentInformationManagementInterface">
<plugin name="save-name" type="Your\Module\Model\Checkout\PoInformationManagementPlugin"/>
```

*then after write to your save logic.*

```
public function beforeSavePaymentInformation(
    \Magento\Checkout\Api\PaymentInformationManagementInterface $subject,
    $cartId,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress
) {
    $additionaldata = $paymentMethod->getAdditionalData();

    $netsixty_upload_path = isset($additionaldata['netsixty_upload_path']) ? $additionaldata['netsixty_upload_path'] : '';
    $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
    if (isset($netsixty_upload_path)) {
        $quote->setNetsixtyUploadPath($netsixty_upload_path);
    }
}
```

> Then after to save sales order table in etc/event.xml

```
<event name="sales_order_save_before">
<observer name="save_additional_data_name" instance="Your\Module\Observer\Saveadditionaldata"/>
```

*then after write to your save logic.*

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
     // write your code
}
```